# How to make an included PDF page linked to an url?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, pdfpages, include, links

I have a **PDF title page** included in the main document, using the `pdfpages` package, as shown in the MWE code below.  I know that all the hyper links included in that page are lost in the process.  But I'm now wondering if it's possible to make the whole included **title page** as a clickable page, that would link to some URL.  If so, how?  I checked the `pdfpages` documentation and it wasn't clear how we could do this.  Any suggestion?

And if it's possible, can we make the clickable **title page** to open **several URLs** at once?

Here's a MWE code to play with:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=red,citecolor=blue,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Name},pdfsubject={Subject},pdfkeywords={some words},pdfproducer={pdfLaTeX},plainpages=false,hyperindex=true,pdfpagelabels,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{TitlePage.pdf} % Not included in this example.  To be made as clickable to URL.

TEST

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
 \AtPageLowerLeft{%
  \href{https://www.latex-project.org/news/2020/07/22/latex-dev-2020-10-1b/}{\rule{0pt}{\textheight}\hspace*{\textwidth}}}}
\includepdf{example-image-letter.pdf} %  

TEST

\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently, this works much better if you use pdfpageheight and pdfpagewidth, instead of textheight ...  I suggest that you edit your answer. Also, could we open several url links at once ?